# computing a correlation for every type of event that occurs in the data set

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, correlation

I rewrote the eloquent javascript code, breaking it down to my own understanding differently from the short hand form in the book. After running the code, instead of my events be put in my empty "let events = 0;" array and recheck for "!events.includes(event)" then do "events.push(event)". I expect the events be pushed to my empty array but instead event's arrays from the JOURNAL data are pushed into my empty event leaving it with all the events and not one array of only the list of every events.

```js
function journalEvents(journal) {
  let events = [];
  for (i = 0; i < journal.length; i++) {
   let entry = journal[i];
    for (j = 0; j < journal.length; j++) {
     let event = entry.events;
      if (!events.includes(event)) {
        events.push(event);
      }
    }
  }
  return events;
}

console.log(journalEvents(JOURNAL));
// Why am I getting an array in and array instead → [["carrot", "exercise", "weekend"], …]
```

Bellow is the Eloquent code that work perfectly and i cant find the difference between my own rewrote code from the short hand. Can someone tell me why mine is not sorting out all the events instead of pushing JOURNAL[i].event into my array?....

```js
function journalEvents(journal) {
  let events = [];
  for (let entry of journal) {
    for (let event of entry.events) {
      if (!events.includes(event)) {
        events.push(event);
      }
    }
  }
  return events;
}

console.log(journalEvents(JOURNAL));
// This is the ectaul expected result (A single array of events) → ["carrot", "exercise", "weekend", "bread", …]
```

```js
// can someone please break this code down for me line by line?

function journalEvents(journal) {

  /* how come this block could use the same name "events" as it is in the 
  JOURNAL data to set its output collections of arrays and does not affect the 
  code "JOURNAL[i].events" in the date when it loop through?. 
  Isn't that variable declaration at the begining of the loop sets the events 
  in the JOURNAL data to an empty array everytime it runs?*/
  
  let events = [];
  for (let entry of journal) {
    for (let event of entry.events) {
      if (!events.includes(event)) {
      
  /* Why are the events pushed in individually and not in their arrays? */
  
        events.push(event);
      }
    }
  }
  return events;
}


console.log(journalEvents(JOURNAL));
// → ["carrot", "exercise", "weekend", "bread", …]
```

Comment: Where is the code?

Comment: the code goes into the question, not in the comments under the question.

Comment: You guys, stop down voting people just because they are noobs. OP's question is well formatted and gives clear examples, and he is very specific about what he is asking. Quit being elitists ffs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between your two scripts is the use of the `of` keyword in the loop, which means *iterate over the values and ignore the keys*.

In your loop, you are using `j` as a designator for the key, but you are not pushing based on key association, and are instead pushing the entire value of `event`, where you should be pushing `event[j]`, as per the following:

```
if (!events.includes(event[j])) {
    events.push(event[j]);
}
```

This is based on the assumption of values of the original `JOURNAL` dataset, which was not provided in your example, however there is enough in your comments at the bottom of the snippets to derive what the issue was, where `JOURNAL` would likely be something like the following (purely an educated guess):

```
[
    ["carrot", "exercise", "weekend"],
    ["carrot", "exercise", "weekend"],
    // ... etc
]
```

---

The `of` operator is part of the [ES6 specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of), which was included to replace the common traditionally clunky way of iterating with a `for ... in` *without including prototype values*, which would traditionally look something like the following:

```
for (i in object)
{
    if (object.hasOwnPrototype(i))
    {
        var.push(i);
    }
}
```

This is obviously somewhat unwieldly, as `for ... in` iterates over *all keys including the prototype chain* (where it is most common to not want to iterate the prototype chain), and `foreach` has traditionally been poor performance wise, hence the addition of the `for ... of` loop. If you are emulating this with `for (i=0; i < some_array.length; i++)`, then you need to explicitly reference values with the key `i` like `object[i]`, which also only works for arrays, and not objects which are associatively keyed with strings. `for ... of` works for both though, as well as any other array-like object, making it significantly more versatile and overall reducing complexity and redundancy of your code.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation